# Ignore rows which contain a hyphen in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table like so

```
Words   | count
hello   | 2
bye     | 1
good-bye| 2
```

How can I remove/ignore rows containing hyphens (I think using regex)? So the output is

```
hello   | 2
bye     | 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simpliest solution is to use `LIKE`

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableName
WHERE  words NOT LIKE '%-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use not like

```
where words not like '%-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table NOT REGEXP /*-*/;
```